# jquery select options remove initial option and replace with others

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the below piece of jquery which adds new options to the select input via ajax.  However the select initially has one option which I would like to remove and then replace with the options returned via ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#id_previous_postcode').change(function () {
    var postcode = $(this).val()
    console.log(postcode)
    $.ajax({
      // could prevent url hard coding by using url tag in form widget attribute and assign url key here to that attr
      url: '/users/prior_addresses_ajax/',
      data: {
        'postcode': postcode
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        var select = document.querySelector('#id_previous_full_address');
        console.log(data)
        data.property_choices.forEach(function (subarray) {
          var option = new Option(subarray[1], subarray[0]);
          select.options.add(option);
        });
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you post what your selector looks like before the jQuery is triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using jQuery, you can `.empty()` the select.

```
success: function (data) {

        // Will remove previous set options from select
        $('#id_previous_full_address').empty();

        var select = document.querySelector('#id_previous_full_address');
        console.log(data)
        data.property_choices.forEach(function (subarray) {
          var option = new Option(subarray[1], subarray[0]);
          select.options.add(option);
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use

```
$("SELECTOR").first().detach();
```

And then...

```
$("NEW ELEMENT").preppendTo($("SELECTOR").first().parent());
```